# Are student papers treated differently from main papers in a top conference?

Tags: publications, conference

This is referring to a top tier conference like AAAI, CVPR, NIPS.

Other than the apparent difference that the lead author is a student, how differently are student papers treated? Will the reviewers be less harsh on the paper, and if accepted, will it be given the same amount of recognition as the main conference papers? Is there any segregation done when the final papers are presented at the conferences?

Comment: AAAI and NIPS (I don't know about CVPR on the top of my head) are double blind. So, the reviewer does not know that all authors are students!

Comment: I doubt there are 'student' papers in these top conferences.  I'm sure the supervisor(s) has spent considerable effort on the paper. In other words, if you are a newbie or inexperienced (including researchers), your chances are low.  You need someone with a track record at these conferences.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus There absolutely _are_ papers at top CS conferences written entirely by students, with minimal or no involvement from their advisors or other faculty.

Comment: @JeffE Well I guess your definition of 'student' is different to mine.  I can always do another PhD and get myself labeled as a 'student'.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus My definition of "student" is "someone without a PhD", and on very rate occassiona even "somone without a bachelors degree".

Comment: @JeffE my point is, someone without a degree can function at the same or higher level than someone with a PhD.  If Freeman Dyson decides to do a PhD, and become a 'PhD student', I'm sure he won't have any problems getting published in top places.

Answer (score 2):

In my area of research there is no special category or process for student papers. All papers are submitted using the same process and the overwhelming majority of conferences uses double blind peer-review.

By design this implies that reviewers should not even be aware whether a paper was written by a student or not. Also during conferences, all papers are treated exactly the same.

The only thing I can think of that's special for papers written by students is that some conferences offer a special "Best Student Paper" award, for which - naturally - only student papers are eligible. (What defines a student paper can differ between conferences.) But these awards are decided after all accepted papers have been chosen and do not influence acceptance/rejection.